# GUI tool to search files in jar

Tags: 13.10, files, gui, search

I am looking for a GUI search tool which searches inside a folder and its sub folders(recursively) including archive files contents(Jar, Zip, tar etc).

I saw the krusader search dialog but unfortunately it is not supporting jar archives(Support only tar,zip etc).
See [here](http://www.krusader.org/documentation/krusearcher.html).

Note: We need to select "Search in archives" option.
 Is there any way to include jars in krusader search or 
Is there any alternative GUI tool exists to do this.

Note that I tried **gnome-search-tool** or **nautilus search tool** but these are not suitable.

Comment: I think archive manager does it

Comment: No it works on a single jar not on multiple jars

Comment: select the two jar files and right click on it and then select open with archive manager.

Comment: ufff.It is not the answer.If have 100 jar files in sub-folders(recursively) then how can I select all these?

Comment: If you go into Files, go to the directory you want, Ctrl+F and type `.jar`. Then you can Ctrl+S, type `*.jar` and hit Enter. It then should select all of the .jar files... Does it have to be GUI - there is alot of stuff on using the `find` command...

Comment: @wilf I am not **ONLY** looking in jar files.Along with jar files I want to include normal .java and/or .class files.I want to list all files in a given folder and its sub-folders(**RECURSIVELY**) whose names are matching with the search string given by user.Also this search should include jar files and its contents.

Comment: The below answer is not graphical, but it should find files with multiple search terms - *(I ain't checked it though :-s)*

Comment: `Jar` files are `zip` files. That they are not searched by krusader is probably a measure to not flood your output with the contents of programs you want to execute. The same applies to `epub`. So renaming would do the trick. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939134/bash-command-search-for-class-in-file-system-of-jars) is a jar specific solution for what you want, but you will have to do a set of similar actions for all the other archive types you want to have a look into.

Answer (score 0):

This is not graphical, but will give a list of files and folders, which is sort of what you want - run this in terminal

```
cd /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY && find -iname "*.jar" && find -iname "*.class"
```

This will find just those ending with `.jar`:

```
cd /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY && find -iname "*.jar"
```

This will find just those ending with `.class`:

```
cd /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY && find -iname "*.class"
```